Is "hidden away" an adjective?

Everybody in Raveloe talks of the weaver's money — he must have a lot hidden away in that cottage!

Is "hidden away" an adjective ?

Would you ask the very same question under a slightly different word order? Everybody in Raveloe talks of the weaver's money — he must have hidden a lot away in that cottage!

No, not an adjective. "Hidden away" is a verb + preposition construction.

Although "hidden" is both a past participle and an adjective, in the present context it has to be taken together with "away" as the past participle form of "to hide away" the multi-word verb meaning "to conceal". Although you might find "a hidden-away place" (rare), this combination has not attained to the rank of adjective, as for instance "faraway", "breakaway", and more relevantly "castaway" (castaway sailor/thing).  It has to be treated as "taken away" in the following sentence, where it might appear more evident  that "taken away" is not an adjective.

They have had a lot taken away from them.


hidden-away place

Why? Huddleston & Pullum would say that words like "accounted for" are compound adjectives, not past participle + preposition sequences, as shown by the fact that you can add the negating prefix "un-" to get "unaccounted for."

@alphabet If H&P said that "accounted for" was a compound adjective, then they would hyphenate it "accounted-for", which is not the case. They consider "account for" to be verb+prep, where "account" is prepositional verb, and "accounted for" is a bare passive clause.

@alphabet I think that this is so because none of the criteria for adjectives are satisfied. The attributive use is quasi-inexistant for this term. "Hidden-away place" has been used but rarely, and apparentlly you don't find such combinations as "a hidden-away car/sum of money/…".  Predicative use after the copula "seem" is unthinkable.  Premodification by "very" is also unthinkable. Comparison ("more hidden-away", as hidden-away as", …) is not possible. If a certain number of cases such as "hidden-away place" (car, house, etc.) (1/2)

@alphabet were found in the language, then, yes, this term would qualify as an adjective, not a "full" adjective though, but the satisfaction of this criterion would suffice for the purpose of acknowledging "hidden-away" as an adjective; it would be what is called a peripheral adjective (the least adjective-like words). "Castaway" is such an adjective. (2/2)
